# Resources about integral maximization problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, computational-complexity

I am looking at the following problem. Given an interval I, and a function f over that interval, find sub-intervals for which:

1. The sum of the length of the sub-intervals is < k;
2. The sub-intervals are mutually disjoint;
3. The sum of the integrals over the sub-intervals is maximum.

I think this problem is NP-complete. But I am not sure about it. Any resources about this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: It might matter how $f$ is given/represented.

Comment: Is the number of subintervals fixed?

Comment: yes, f representation matter. lets simply assume it is continuous function and the number of sub-interval is fixed.
actually I think that the problem can be thought as the knapsack problem in sense that we have k sub-intervals each with length and value of sub integral or as cost limited set cover problem in sense we have k subsets each with cost equals its length and want maximize coverage.
However, I need to know more about the problem and if there is study about it.